# iPhone app kill process

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, process

I am basically looking to create Memory (RAM) optimization function as given in following applications. (For iPhone sdk)

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memory-100-pro/id644853504?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/th/app/memory-pro/id483447668?mt=8

This function basically kills third party app background process to achieve the same.

Can any one guide me that how can I find that particular process is not system process and kill the process.

I am using following code to get list of process with process id.

```
struct kinfo_proc *procs = NULL, *newprocs;
char          thiscmd[MAXCOMLEN + 1];
pid_t           thispid;
int           mib[4];
size_t                miblen;
int           i, st, nprocs;
size_t                size;


size = 0;
mib[0] = CTL_KERN;
mib[1] = KERN_PROC;
mib[2] = KERN_PROC_ALL;
mib[3] = 0;
miblen = 3;

st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
do {
    size += size / 10;
    newprocs = realloc(procs, size);
    if (newprocs == 0) {
        if (procs)
            free(procs);
        errx(1, "could not reallocate memory");
    }
    procs = newprocs;
    st = sysctl(mib, miblen, procs, &size, NULL, 0);
} while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

nprocs = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

/* Now print out the data */
for (i = 0; i < nprocs; i++) {
    thispid = procs[i].kp_proc.p_pid;
    strncpy(thiscmd, procs[i].kp_proc.p_comm, MAXCOMLEN);
    thiscmd[MAXCOMLEN] = '\0';
    printf("%d\t%s\n", thispid, thiscmd);

    NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", procs[i].kp_proc.p_comm];
    if([processName isEqualToString:@"templerunbrave"])
        kill(thispid, SIGKILL);


}

/* Clean up */
free(procs);
```

Comment: Is this for jailbroken phones, or for the App Store?

Comment: the mentioned apps don't kill anything

Comment: Its for App store @Nate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A 3rd party app is sandboxed and does not have the power or authority to arbitrarily kill processes and threads that do not belong to it.

The way these "memory" apps work is by manually allocating memory incrementally in a for loop until they get memory warnings, then manually freeing the memory. Because the OS does not know that your memory is not being used in the app, it takes active memory away from other apps, sometimes even force closing them in order to provide their memory resources to your app. Once you manually free the memory, this memory that was allocated to your app is now available to the whole system, but the other apps which were killed or in deep sleep will remain killed or in deep sleep.

Comment: Agree.  I always wondered if those types of programs were bunk or not.  At least it "sort of makes sense" how they work.